# Connecting in Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas airport to travel to the UK

Tags: schengen, us-citizens, mad

I'm connecting in Madrid from Israel to the UK.

Do I have to go through Immigration into Spain and get my US passport stamped or is it like an international connection through a transit area?

Also If I dont need to get stamped and I want to anyway, Is a 2hr stopover long enough to exit and re-enter?

Answer (score 2):

It depends:

> Passengers who have to take another flight and/or continue with
>   another airline company (passengers in transit), may need to change
>   terminal due Adolfo Suarez Madrid-Barajas airport has two large hubs,
>   one at the terminal T4, and another at terminals T1, T2 and T3.
>
> Time required to reach connecting flights varies depending on the
>   route, the airline, whether you need to pick up your luggage if not
>   checked to destination, or you must change terminal. Note that if you
>   do not have a boarding pass for your next flight and/or you have to
>   need to pick up your luggage that is not checked to destination, you
>   must leave the boarding area, pass through immigration controls if
>   any, and make a new check-in to your airline check-in counter. Then
>   you will need to pass through security checkpoints to re-enter the
>   boarding area. Keep in mind you should add additional time to this
>   process if you must to change terminal.
>
> Passengers in transit without their next boarding pass, and/or have to
>   need to pick up their checked luggage that is not checked to
>   destination, they have a 24 hours free shuttle bus service connecting
>   T1, T2, T3 and T4 terminals from the outside. Access to T4S can only
>   be done from inside the boarding area of terminal T4.
>
> For passengers in transit who already have their boarding pass and
>   baggage checked to destination, the connections between terminals can
>   be made as follows:
>
> - From terminal T1 to T4 Satellite through a free bus service connecting baggage claim hall 1 terminal T1 and terminal T4 Satellite.
> - From terminal T1 to terminals T2 - T3 through a free bus service connecting baggage claim hall 1 and baggage claim hall 2 terminal T1,
>     and baggage claim hall 6 terminal T2. This connection can walking be
>     done, through security checkpoints, and takes around 10 minutes.
> - Connections between terminal T4 and Terminal T4 Satellite must be done by automatic underground train (APM).

[Madrid Airport](http://www.aeropuertomadrid-barajas.com/eng/flight-connections.htm).

Answer (score -1):

You are travelling Non Schengen to Non Schengen, so there will be no immigration checks and if you are Israeli citizen you don't need a transit visa.